# Radio button styles not showing in webview

Tags: android, css, webview

I designed some radio buttons with images using css, because I want to make the radio button look bigger.

Now, when I load it in browsers it works fine, same in mobile browsers. But when I try to load it in webview the radio button is not visible. Is there anyway to enable css?

Comment: if you can post html and css can tell u.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enable css. You just link to it from you html file like you normally would

Comment: it is working in other browsers, even in mobile browser but it is not working in webview alone. I have already enable javascript for webview.

Answer (score 0):

if your css file is separate then you need to provide complete relative path in html page you include the html page like file:/// something like that.

mobile brower can take relative path by itself like say your accessing from wampserver but if you are putting all in webview and loading then it dont take relative path by itself. By the way where you are putting all this files in assests or sdcard ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the html, css and image resource files in the assets folder of your project and load the html using "file:///android_asset/yourwebpage.html" as a Url.

Comment: My html page, css and images are in server so that can i try putting all in one folder.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this in a webview because you said you've done it to make the radio button bigger? there are better ways to do that, that don't require the user to have a network connection (which if your files are hosted on a server, they'll need).